# Short-circuiting in coffee/javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

This coffeescript:

```
if  typeof(groups) is undefined or groups.length == 0
```

gets compiled into the following javascript:

```
if (typeof groups === void 0 || groups.length === 0)
```

Basically i want to check if the groups array is null or empty and hoping that if the first condition is true, the second condition will not be checked (short-circuiting).  However Chrome throws the following error:

> Uncaught type error: Cannot read property length of undefined

Any insights on why it wouldnt short-circuit?

Comment: you should also check for `null`

Comment: Hi, please kindly look at my small blog about short circuiting and I hope it could help a little: js-guru.blogspot.com/2015/08/javascript-short-circuiting.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoffeeScript has an operator that takes care of this case for you.  If you use:

```
unless groups?.length > 0
```

it will form what you're looking for, taking care of the undefined/null cases and only trying `groups.length` if `groups` is defined.  This has the advantage of being easily chained:

```
if foo?.bar?.length > 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i think that the first snippet is not equivalent to what the OP is asking for, as it will evaluate to `false` if `groups` is null or undefined.

Comment: Indeed, I took the liberty of fixing it. Still, this is the right way to approach it.

Answer (score 5):

Because the first condition will never be true. `void 0` will evaluate to the value `undefined` (not the string "undefined"), but `typeof` returns the string "undefined".

The JavaScript should read:

```
if (typeof groups === "undefined" || groups.length === 0)
```

Or:

```
if (groups === void 0 || groups.length === 0)
```

To fix your CoffeeScript, you need to check for the string "undefined":

```
if typeof groups is "undefined" or groups.length == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If `groups` is a local variable, you can ask:

```
if not groups or groups.length is 0
  ...
```

If it's a global variable that may not be defined (i.e. accessing `groups` will throw a "not defined" error), you can use the existential operator `?`:

```
if not groups? or groups.length is 0
  ...
```

Finally, as you're asking for the `length` property in the second condition, you can take advantage of the fact that 0 is falsy:

```
if not groups?.length
  ...
```

And this last expression won't care if the `groups` variable is defined or not; it'll work on both cases =D